# Is it useful to normalize or standardize if your features are binary?

Tags: neural-networks

I have binary features that I am training on a machine learning model. For example:

```
<0, 0, 1>

<1, 0, 0>
```

I am going to train a neural network on this data. Should I normalize the data before training? I don't think I have to since its already in 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need normalize the data if they all are the same. Normalization is good when you have features with different numerical bounds, for example:

```
10, 0.0003,   100000
20, 0.00013, 1000000
...
```

If you try put these data in some network, the bigger numbers will make a greater contribution to the network output. All data should be equivalent with respect to their numerical bounds.